# I'm more in Olympics than in one of the German Big Three. What Am I?

Tags: riddle

> I'm more in Olympics than in one of the German Big Three.
>
> I'm bigger on the sixth rock than when engaged.
>
> I'm variable when you call or cut a tree.

What am I?

Comment: I advise you make up a title which is something like the current one but you chose it, 'Riddle: What am I?' is too broad but something like 'Bigger on the sixth rock: What am I?' would be perfect

Comment: And welcome to puzzling! pretty good first riddle, but maybe make future ones a bit longer so they don't get closed as too broad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a

> ring

I'm more in Olympics than in one of the German Big Three.

> Per celtschk's more complete explanation "The Olympic sign is five rings. The German Big Three are Audi, Mercedes and BMW; of those, Audi has four rings as sign."

I'm bigger on the sixth rock than when engaged.

> Saturn rings versus a wedding ring.

I'm variable when you call or cut a tree.

> When you call the phone rings, rings on a tree stump.

Comment: Good job! Was it a bit too easy? :P

Comment: @Andrew, I thought it was good for a first riddle! Nice.

Comment: hehe, thanks. I'll try to think up some that take a bit more guessing! :)

Comment: @Andrew Don't forget to accept the answer if it is the right one :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a

> ring.

I'm more in Olympics than in one of the German Big Three.

> The Olympic sign is five rings. The German Big Three are Audi, Mercedes and BMW; of those, Audi has four rings as sign.

I'm bigger on the sixth rock than when engaged.

> The rings of Saturn (sixth planet from the sun) are larger than engagement rings.

I'm variable when you call or cut a tree.

> When called, the telephone rings; that ring is different for different phones. Trees have year rings that also differ from each other.